# aiohttp SSLError wrong version number

Tags: python, ssl, asyncio, aiohttp

использую список прокси типа HTTP для отправки запроса, с какого - то  прокси выкидывает ошибку:

```
2019-01-07 23:53:30,164 ERROR:SSL handshake failed
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x00000204F3F4DAC8>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=1852 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)
2019-01-07 23:53:30,164 ERROR:SSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x00000204F3F4DAC8>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=1852 read=idle write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Как ее можно исправить?

```
# Создаём клиентскую сессию
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        client = await login(client)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
            # Создаём корневую футуру
            initial_future = loop.create_future()
            # Помещаем в неё ссылки, с которых начнём парсить
            initial_future.set_result(root_urls)
            # Передаём эту футуру в сопрограмму обхода ссылок
            # вместе с пулом потоков и клиентской сессией
            # await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
            await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
```

Метод для отправки запросов:

```
async def request(client, url):
    global limit, headers, use_proxy
    if(use_proxy):
        proxy = await get_current_proxy()
    else:
        proxy = None
    for i in range(15):
        async with limit:
            try:
                async with client.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=proxy) as r:
                    log.info('Запрос: %s, - %s', url, str(r.status))
                    if(r.status == 200):
                        return [await r.text(), url]
                    else:
                        if(r.status == 500):
                            break
                        log.info("Ошибка статус: %s", r.status)
                        await asyncio.sleep(i)
            except:
                await asyncio.sleep(i)
```

Иногда выкидывает эту ошибку:

```
2019-01-07 23:58:41,218 ERROR:SSL handshake failed on verifying the certificate
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x00000200AAB05EF0>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=1764 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)
```

Но ведь сертификат вроде есть только у HTTPS, разве нет?

Comment: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER - подключаешься по тлс, а сервер умеет только ссл

CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED - прокси подменяет сертификат для того чтоб просматривать содержимое запросов

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуй:

   async with client.get(url, headers=headers, proxy=proxy, ssl=False)

Это отключит проверку сертификата.

2. Ты используешь HTTP прокси для HTTPS соединений по этому и получаешь первую ошибку (ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number)

Comment: ваше решение не помогло